# CCAvenue Transaction Error Page Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have integrate ccavenue in my magento store but when i place the order from my magento store and after checkout it will redirect to an ccavanue error page https://www.ccavenue.com/errorPages/Error.jsp?errorCode=0

[image]

I have already configure merchant id and working key in my magento store.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Solution is to use latest version of ccAvenue magento integration kit.(i.e.1.9.0.1)

Comment: Have you installed this extension [http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ccavenue-payment-gateway-free.html] I have installed version number : Version number: 0.2.8. but problem is still.